# Use of the word left to indicate remaining

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

My friend told me

> Only 4 people out of 35 have been able to complete the Quiz till now

I replied

> A lot of people are left

Is that a correct answer/English?
What I meant to say is that many people have yet to complete the Quiz. Is the use of left correct here?

Answer (score 2):

This is more a question about whether your answer was clear.

And it's not, although your meaning can be inferred from the context.

The same would be true if you said: **That leaves a lot of people** meaning, **That leaves a lot of people to complete it**,  or **A lot of people are left to complete it,** which is fine.

If this is about a disagreement with your friend, the answer is that s/he should have understood exactly what you meant.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My friend didn't understand what I meant. I thought maybe I was using incorrect English. But he should have inferred from the context since we were talking about i.